# ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size in python

Tags: python

I have downloaded a .nc file and have checked the file to make sure that it is not empty. I have tried to read the file in python as below:

```
sh = S.netcdf_file('_grib2netcdf-atls15-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-grVIhe.nc','r')
```

but it gives the error:

```
ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size
```

I have searched a lot to find the reason but most of them are related to empty files which I am sure this file is not empty. Does anybody have any idea about it? Your helps are really appreciated.

Comment: http://earthdef.caltech.edu/boards/3/topics/224, this might help.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening with mode='r+'. That way you give numpy permission to extend the file size to accommodate the larger memmaps.